# Trimming Video File WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

im fairly new to C# and im trying my look at making a windows phone app, in the app i need it to cut down a video file. after hours of searching and asking around someone pointed me to this 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868176.aspx

```
async void TrimVideoFile()
 {
Windows.Storage.StorageFile source;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile destination;

var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

source = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();

savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation =
    Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

savePicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".mp4";
savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Video";

savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("MPEG4", new string[] { ".mp4" });

destination = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

// Method to perform the transcoding.
TrimFile(source, destination);
```

}

I Have tried using this in the app i am making and it states on the page

**Windows Phone Store app must use pickSingleFileAndContinue.**

i have tried different combinations with the code, as stated im a novice.

I keep getting different errors, is there anyone who can advise on how to get this to work on WP8.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the Windows Phone platform, you must use (as the documentation and compiler told you) `PickSingleFileAndContinue()`. This requires the use of a [Continuation Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614994.aspx) so you can pick up app execution where it left -- at the file selection.

The same goes for `PickSaveFileAsync()`, which must be `PickSaveFileAndContinue()` on WP; again, you need the Continuation manager.

Now, both of these methods are synchronous, so you can't use await on them.

Something I'm wondering about: The `TrimFile` is `async void`. If you change that to `async Task`, you could prepend the TrimFile call with async and retain the asynchronicity (as you can't await void).
I can't test if this works as I don't have a WP device on my hands right now.